# Understanding Hinted Handoffs and Data replication in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

We have a 3 node Cassandra cluster with RF = 2. The read and write consistency is set to ONE. We are using Vnodes as well. Lets label these nodes as N1, N2 and N3. Let's say that N3 goes down. I was under the impression that whenever a node goes down, the other nodes would store hints and whenever N3 comes up, the hints would be sent to N3, thereby ensuring that the data is consistent across replicas. However, as I was going through the docs, I came across the parameter `max_hint_window_in_ms` which defaults to 3 hours. So, if a node is dead for more than 3 hours, it is considered permanently dead and no hints are stored. So far, so good.

So, my understanding now is that if a node is down for say 10 hours, then the hints for the first 3 hours would be transferred to this node when it comes back up, but the writes for this 7 hour duration would be lost for this node. Moreover, if a read query is fired for a particular token range, and since this node is also elligible to serve the read requests for a token range, it would return null instead of the actual data that is stored in some other node. Is my understanding correct? What, then, should be done?

Comment: Is this being tested and the behavior is unexpected? Or are you looking for the expected behavior if the scenario were to occur? Since you have consistency level set to ONE, all read/writes should be successful (assuming throughput is not large).

Comment: I am trying to evaluate as to what the behaviour would be if one of my nodes went down for a period of more than 3 hours( the default value of max_hint_window_in_ms).

Answer (score 2):

> What, then, should be done?

The docs state that when you bring the down node (N3) back, that you would then have to run a repair on it.

Honestly though, in most of our clusters, I find it easier to simply remove the node (while it is down) and then re-bootstrap it into the cluster.  That usually goes faster than computation of Merkle trees and streaming of repair data.  But if you don't have a lot of data per node (say less than 20GB), running a repair shouldn't be too painful.

Comment: I guess you are right. We have about 100 gb of data per node, growing at the rate of about 5-10 gb daily. Repairs are quite painful. Have to leave them overnight. But since hinted handoffs are part of the repair process, and they are retained only for a 3 hour period(default value), wouldn't we still be losing the data for the period after 3 hours, even after running a repair?

Comment: @Ankush92 No, your RF=2 ensures that at least one replica will be written.  When you repair/bootstrap the target node will use that replica to stream data to it.